# Plastic material for a dice

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I'm working on a material for a dice. My first attempt below has a more velvet look:

[image]

Then I've downloaded a material from Blendswap with this outcome:

[image]

I like the top of the dice, but the rest is not OK. After finding a tutorial on how to create a glossy plastic the dice looks like this (I used the same red color for the diffuse and glossy shader):

[image]

I've used the same red color for the diffuse and glossy shader which results in a less plastic look. After changing the color of the glossy shader to white the dice looks like:

[image]

The top looks more plastic, but the rest is not quite what I want.

#### Question

How can I improve my material to get a 'realistic' plastic look for my dice? Below you can find a screen shot of my current setup:

[image]

After removing the relecting floor (and a little adjustment of the lighting and applying the material setup as above) I got the outcome shown below. I am sort of pleased with the plastic look but now I have lost my reflective floor ....and I don't like that. How to create an image with the plastic look and the reflective floor ??? Or would that be a Photoshop job ?

[image]

[image]

---

I am looking for a plastic material like [this](http://www.cliparthut.com/rolling-dice-clip-art-clipart-tO29Fj.html) or [this](http://www.qualitylogoproducts.com/stress-balls/dice-stress-reliever.htm).

*I'm a beginner and I'd appreciate a explanation or some instructions how to achieve this. Thanks.*

Comment: it would help if you linked to a specific example of the kind of material effect you _are_ looking for.

Comment: You can put on background HDRI and have a better look at your dice's material

Comment: Hows this? http://www.pasteall.org/pic/92044

Comment: Could you put your .blend file on BlendeExchange? http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ We have this because hosting services like pasteall remove the .blends after a few months, and when something is put on dropbox, google drive, etc, it will usually get deleted later on to preserve space. The reason why this is important, is because StackExchange isn't supposed to just be here so that people can ask question and have them answered, it's a resource that people can look back at, and if something that was used to explain something, and it's missing a resource (,blend file) it's now useless.

Comment: So you want glossy surface, but you don't like the floor reflection in the dice? Get rid of the floor.

Comment: @ TARDIS Maker I added the file to Blend Exchange. Regarding your suggestion: yes, I like the top of your dice but the vertical faces are still a lighter color of red. If the vertical faces would be like the top face I would be very happy I think. I don't think this is because of the floor reflection. Can you upload your blend file too ?

Comment: @ TARDIS Maker I removed the floor and I guess the reason for the vertical faces being a "lighter red" is because of the floor. Could you upload your blend file because i believe your material is the right one.

Comment: @Jerryno Is it possible to create a render that don't has the floor reflections and still has a white floor ?? Or should I solve that in Photoshop ??

Comment: @JanScherders Sorry, I didn't get a notification for your comments (I'm pretty sure it won't notify me if there are spaces between TARDIS and Maker). Are you wanting it on a pure white background then? I could simply remove the floor, enable transparency, and then in post add a white background.

Comment: @TARDISMaker I would like that. Could you please upload the Blend file ? I don't quite understand what you mean with "enable transparency"

Comment: @TARDISMaker As I understand it you recommend to remove the floor and add it again in post. I did experiment (for instance with roughness and the mixed shader factor) but couldn't bring down the reflectiveness of the floor enough. Is there no way to keep the floor in the scene AND have no ugly reflections on the dice ?

Comment: Give me a little bit and I'll have an answer for you. You really shouldn't need the .blend file. I just used a custom fresnel node that I like to use, and got rid of your mesh lights. It's possible to have the floor in the scene and not reflect, but I wouldn't recommend it. It will just end up looking weird. The floor and the die wouldn't match up properly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

maybe the problem is the light bouncing from the floor to the dice.
-try to do it in blender render.
-put the floor in other layer(2).
-select the lamp. 
-click the "this layer only".
-make sure that the dice and the lamp are in the same layer(1).
-select the two layer(1),layer(2).
-then render.......

Comment: I hope you realize that he's talking about rendering in cycles.

Comment: I think you were right !! The material I created did the job pretty well (although I would like the material a bit less glossy). But you were right ... the reflection of the floor caused the "light red" vertical faces.